# Error While Trying to Run Local Service with a specific user: The remote server has been paused or is in the process of being started

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

I want to run a custom process running as local windows service with a specific user I have created instead of Local System account.

I have successfully applied Service Logon permissions and Service Logon credentials.

I can run the service with my user account on my own developer machine.

However, While testing this configuration on a testing machine with a test user, I get the following error:

"The YourCustom service terminated with the following service-specific error: The remote server has been paused or is in the process of being started."

this is a win32 error with code 70 ERROR_SHARING_PAUSED.

The user has the write rights to the installation directory. I use Windows 10 as testing environment and I wonder if I need to give extra permissions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it need Modify rights? Write only allows it to write new data, and does not allow it to modify existing data.

Comment: @music2myear thanks, the problem stems from another issue: the newly created user did not open a session and I was trying to start the service from administrator account. When I login as the custom user for the first time, the service started to work

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from a very simple detail:

I had not open a session with my specific user after creating that account and I was trying to start the service from administrator account. When I login as the this user for the first time, the service started to work.

This is a very rare error because almost no one tries to change a service logon credentials to a newly created use without opening a session with that new user at least once.